# Delete data frame lines with multiple variables values conditions R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I wanted to delete lines from a data frame based on multiple variables values.

In my example below, I wanted to delete lines from March 2022 (and only them). This means that both of my conditions must be true (m = March AND Y = 2022) to have a kind of overall condition True. I tried using `subset` or `filter` function as I think `dplyr` package is a way easier and powerfull. However i did not succeed to delete these lines. Here's my code  with `subset` function as example :

```
library(tidyverse)
m <-  c("March","March","March", "April", "May","June")
Y <-  c("2022","2022","2021","2022","2022","2022")
N <- c(152,75,869,421,748,52)

df <- data.frame(m,Y,N)
df

df<- df %>% 
  subset(m != "March" & Y !="2022")
df
```

Here's the console return :

```
> df
[1] m Y N
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Any requests ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rephrase the `filter` to simultaneously include both criteria:

```r
df %>% 
  filter(!(m == "March" & Y == "2022"))  

      m    Y   N
1 April 2022 421
2   May 2022 748
3  June 2022  52
```